# User-Defined Session variables using in IN() function returns unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5

For example I have a table named `TABLE` and it has a single field named `FIELD` with values **1** and **2**. Running this statement

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`FIELD`)  
INTO @LIST 
FROM `TABLE`;
```

and

```
SELECT @LIST;
```

returns

> 1,2

then I do an **IF()** statement

```
SELECT IF (1 IN(@LIST),"TRUE","FALSE");
```

returns

> TRUE

**BUT** when I run this one

```
SELECT IF (2 IN(@LIST),"TRUE","FALSE");
```

it returns

> FALSE

so I try this statement for a little debugging

```
SELECT IF (2 IN(1,2),"TRUE","FALSE");
```

and it returns my expected value

> TRUE

So is there something that I missed? I need it to return **TRUE**.

Comment: In your statement, `@LIST` is effectively equivalent to a single string literal `'1,2'`. But it's being evaluated in a numeric context, MySQL is evaluating that to be equal to integer `1`. (Try `SELECT @LIST+0`, and `SELECT @LIST+4`, see what is returned. So, your predicate is effectively `SELECT 1 IN (1)`. In single quotes, `SELECT '1' IN ('1,2')` results will be different.  **Bottom line:** the **comma** inside the string (whether a literal or udv) is **not** going to be interpreted as part of SQL text. You can use string comparison functions on string literal or udv e.g. `FIND_IN_SET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `@LIST` has one string type value: `'1,2'`. To test value is in this values list you must use string function: [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT IF (FIND_IN_SET(1, @LIST), "TRUE","FALSE");
SELECT IF (FIND_IN_SET(2, @LIST), "TRUE","FALSE");
```

Test here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fce1d/1

Comment: Neat solution it is important to understand that IN does not take a comma separated string as input but a list of comma separated values as input.

Answer (score 0):

The in statement is looking for comma separated values which can be strings, integers, doubles and floats to name a few. You can use the in statement for most datatypes. What datatype is @LIST? A varchar? Your @LIST is a string that looks like this `'1,2'` not a comma separated value list like `1,2`. Small subtle but very important difference. You cannot use the IN statement like you are trying above.

However if you created the query as a string and then executed the string as dynamic sql I bet it would work.

So try the following:

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`FIELD`)  
 INTO @LIST 
 FROM `TABLE`;

 SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT IF (2 IN(',@LIST,'),"TRUE","FALSE");'); 

 PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 
 EXECUTE stmt1; 
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Go read about dynamic SQL.